# How much does armour weight affect stealth?

Tags: fallout-4

I read somewhere, I think in a loading screen tip, that the weight of your armour negatively affects your stealth when sneaking. How much does it affect it? I'm playing a stealthy sniper type character, and I'm trying to figure out whether I'm okay to use the heavier armour I'm finding, or whether I should switch back to some lighter armour.

Comment: It's similar, but it doesn't say how much. I'm trying to figure out how much of a trade-off I would be making by switching to a heavier armour.

Comment: Even so the questions are asking exactly the same thing and the answer of "how much" should be covered in the original question rather than having two near identical questions that answer the same thing, with one having slightly more information

Comment: @kalina These seem like different questions. One asks how, and the answer is heavier makes it harder, the other asks how *much*. That's a different answer, as it would need quantities. The accepted answer to the other question would *not* be an answer to this one. It would certainly be nice if the other question had also asked how *much*, but it didn't. The answer to that question, that it makes it harder, is already a given in this question.

Comment: @DCShannon It's a bit of a grey area, but I think kalina is right. While semantically they are different questions, for the purposes of this site they're the same question, or at least they should be.

Comment: @kalina So you're saying they should ask the other person to change their question?

Comment: @DCShannon I actually asked the other person to change their answer

Comment: @SaintWacko If you're satisfied with that, then okay, but I would also like to know this, and asking someone to put more information in their answer than the question asked for seems like a poor way to address it. Hopefully it works out.

Comment: @DCShannon I do feel as though it would be more likely to get a response as a new question, rather than an attempt to modify an accepted answer, but I also feel that under the rules here, my question should probably be considered a duplicate.